# 3D point to screen position. Discarding the points behind the camera in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glm-math

I'm try to convert a 3D point to its screen position.

this is the code that I use.

```
glm::vec2 screenPosition(const glm::vec3 & _coord) const {
        
  glm::vec4 coord = glm::vec4(_coord, 1);
  
  coord = getProjection() * getView() * coord;
  
  coord.x /= coord.w;
  coord.y /= coord.w;
  coord.z /= coord.w;

  coord.x = (coord.x + 1) * width  * 0.5;
  coord.y = (coord.y + 1) * height * 0.5;
  
  return glm::vec2(coord.x, coord.y);
```

I'm not 100% sure about the code but I do not know how to discard the points that are behind the camera.

Some one can help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `coord.z` (after division by `coord.w`) is not in interval [-1,1] the point should be discarded. The value outside that interval indicates that the point is not in camera frustum which also includes the case when point is behind the camera. For DirectX and Vulkan the interval is [0,1].

Comment: @Rabbid76 yes and the answer is for opengl. I added a remark about DirectX and Vulkan.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do the culling / clipping of primitives is to do it in *clip space*, before the perspective divide.

The default OpenGL clip convention is `-w <= x,y,z, <= w`, and all points which do not fulfill this condition can be discarded (culling). Note that discarding points only works for point primitives, if you deal with more complex primitives (lines, triangles), you need to do actual *clipping*.

In the most general case, you will be using a **perspective** projection, and the clip space `w` value will vary per vertex - and it can be 0 - trying to do the discard in NDC will yield to a division by zero in such cases.

If you only want to deal about clipping points *behind* the camera, you can discard everything which is `w <= 0`, but usually, **additionally**  clipping against the *near plane* makes much more sense (and also invoids some numerical issues when going very close to the camera): `z < -w`.

I'd like to stress on a few details here. The clip condition `-w <= x,y,z, <= w` implies that points which lie truly behind the camera (`w < 0`) must be rejected, but the `w = 0` case is still a bit weird, because the homogeneous point `(0,0,0,0)` would still satisfy the above clip condition (and really yield no useful results when doing the perspective divide). However, OpenGL (and GPUs) do not clip against the plane where the camera is in (`w=0`), but against a view volume, and require you to set up a near plane which is in front of the camera. And in such a scenario, even if `w=0` can occur, it is guaranteed that there is never *both* `w=0` and `z=0` simultaneously, so the `(0,0,0,0)` case is never hit. However, this does not prevent people from actually feeding `(0,0,0,0)` into `gl_Position`, and you can assume that real world implementations will not only reject the `w < 0` case which is directly mandated from the above clip condition, but will reject /clip anything `w <= 0`. Note that primitive clipping where one vertex has clip space coords of `(0,0,0,0)`  will still result in nonsense, but you're explicitly asking for that then.

For an **orthogonal** projection, there is actually no way to clip points behind the camera, because conceptually, the camera is infinitely far away. You still might set up an imagined  "camera position" via your view matrix, and a view volume via the projection matrix, and you can still cull/clip against the *near plane* there (`z < -w`). Note that for practical purposes, an orthogonal projection will yield `w = 1`, so the additional `w <= 0` check required in the perspective case is irrelevant.