# Artefacts when billboarding at positions just behind camera

Tags: opengl, rust, linear-algebra, game-development, glm-math

I am drawing a bunch of billboards/triangles in opengl/rust. I get these artefacts where half my screen has blurry color. after debugging i could find that after transformation, some of the vertices become extremely large. i will put a minimally reproducible example below in rust with glam library for matrices .

```
    let camera_position = [-696.2638, 31.615665, 346.61575];
    let camera_front = [0.72691596, -0.2045585, 0.65555245];
    let vtx_pos = [-714.08, 21.8639, 363.706];
    let fov: f32 = 1.012;
    let width = 1920_f32;
    let height = 1080_f32;
    let up = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0).normalize();

    
    let camera_position = vec3(camera_position[0], camera_position[1], camera_position[2]);
    let camera_front = vec3(camera_front[0], camera_front[1], camera_front[2]);
    let camera_dvec =  camera_position + camera_front;
    dbg!(camera_dvec);
    // make matrix
    let view = Mat4::look_at_lh(camera_position, camera_dvec, up);
    dbg!(view);
    let projection = Mat4::perspective_lh(fov, width / height, 1.0, 5000.0);
    dbg!(projection);
    let vp = projection * view;
    dbg!(vp);

    // left bottom vertex
    let world_vtx = vec4(vtx_pos[0], vtx_pos[1], vtx_pos[2], 1.0);
    dbg!(world_vtx);
    let clip_vtx = vp * world_vtx;
    dbg!(clip_vtx);
    let ndc_vtx = clip_vtx.xyz() / clip_vtx.w;
    dbg!(ndc_vtx);
```

from the above code, we get

```
[src/main.rs:29] world_vtx = Vec4(
    -714.08,
    21.8639,
    363.706,
    1.0,
)
[src/main.rs:31] clip_vtx = Vec4(
    -24.995728,
    -17.885654,
    -0.7529907,
    0.24725342,
)
[src/main.rs:33] ndc_vtx = Vec3(
    -101.09356,
    -72.33734,
    -3.045421,
)
```

I think the W part of the clip_vtx should be around the value of -Z . but its smaller value is causing the normalized device coordinates after perspective division to become huge. this is making triangles obnoxiously large and whenever part of that triangle enters my view frustum, i get weird color artefacts.

Can someone help me find out what i am doing wrong? or this is a normal part of matrix transformations that tutorials don't teach me.

from what i learnt asking around in gamedev discords:
i make a billboard at a position, which is like right behind the camera. this causes some kind of discontinuity where the left vertices stay on extreme left and right vertices go to extreme right due to changing signs become HUGE in ndc and create issues if i don't manually clip them. i still don't know how to deal with that issue of discontinuity. right now i'm just calculating the distance between left and right vertices, and if it is bigger than 2.0 in ndc, i skip rendering that billboard.

is there a better way of determining which positions will have the issue of billboards becoming huge?

Comment: Check your coordinates, it seems your `vtx_pos` is behind the camera. When you look (x-axis) from `-696.2638` in direction `0.72691596`, then `-714.08` is not in front of the camera. You can also easily see that because visible points in clip space have to have x,y,z in range [-w, w].

Comment: @BDL yes, but that vertex is part of a two triangles, and they all form a HUGE triangle and when i rotate my camera a little, part of that triangle comes into my view frustum. which kinda causes issues. what should i do to avoid that?

Comment: Why do you want to "avoid" that? If you have a huge triangle in your world and have it intersecting your view frustum, the output is _correct_. What is the issue you are actually trying to solve here?

Comment: @derhass i don't have a huge triangle. i make  a billboard at a position, which is like right behind the camera. this causes some kind of discontinuity where the left vertices stay on extreme left and right vertices go to extreme right due to changing signs become HUGE in ndc and create issues if i don't manually clip them. i realized it after asking around in multiple discords, but i still don't know how to deal with that issue of discontinuity. right now i'm just calculating the distance between left and right vertices, and if it is bigger than 2.0 in ndc, i skip rendering that billboard.

Comment: That's not clear from the question at all. OpenGL will automatically do all clipping, so the question is completely misleading. If you write your own renderer, then clipping will be essential, otherwise you get absurd artifacts if geometry lies partly behind the camera.

Comment: @derhass yeah. at the time of asking the question, i didn't know about the clipping. even now, i only have understand this stuff :( . i can't even properly put my question into words. so, i will just add these comments to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a few hours of asking and poking other experienced people in graphics programming discord, but i have a better idea of what's happening.
and now that i changed my question, i could see similar question in the past on stack overflow. i just checked a few of them and found a good answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65168709/7484780 .

The whole issue of clipping was because i send triangle/billboard vertices as a vec3 and in vertex shader i do `gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.0)`, so opengl doesn't do any clipping. at the same time, i don't do any clipping either before doing perspective division. So, the unclipped billboards are the artefacts that i am getting, especially right behind the camera.

Comment: If you do the perspective divide manually and just feed in NDC coords to `gl_Position` (which is in _clip space_ for a reason), you do not only bypass the clipping, but also the perspective correction for the interpolation.